# How to migrate "build.gradle" configurations in Android Studio for both project level and module level in Android Studio Bumblebee release?

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-studio-bumblebee

For now [13th Feb 2022] , latest android studio's stable version is [BumbleBee](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2022/01/android-studio-bumblebee-202111-stable.html) . With this version, there are a lot of changes in *build.gradle* (project level) .

So, I wonder if there is any guideline on how to adopt these changes with respect to older *build.gradle* (project level) will be a relief.

Answer (score 2):

to add  Admob and Firebase crashlytics to Android studio bumble bee and other such things

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    // Add our classpath 
     classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
     classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1' 
 }
}
 plugins {
      id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0' apply false
      id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.0' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

for maven jitpack, the JitPack repository needs to be added into the root level file settings.gradle instead of build.gradle:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
      // ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

these are initial changes more may be required as per your own requirements